# Inserting same value twice into database

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code:

```
$text = $_REQUEST["enable"];
$description = 'Debited For Service';

foreach($text as $data)
{
    foreach($check as $data1)
    {
        $insert="INSERT INTO `wallet_transaction`(`wallet_id`, `debit_amount`, `description`) VALUES ('$esc_id', '$data1', '$data', '$description')";
        mysql_query($insert);
    }   
}
```

The result is that these queries are run, but I only want the first two queries:

```
INSERT INTO `wallet_transaction`(`wallet_id`, `debit_amount`, `description`) VALUES ('2', '200', 'Debited For Service')
INSERT INTO `wallet_transaction`(`wallet_id`, `debit_amount`, `description`) VALUES ('3', '100', 'Debited For Service')

INSERT INTO `wallet_transaction`(`wallet_id`, `debit_amount`, `description`) VALUES ('2', '200', 'Debited For Service')
INSERT INTO `wallet_transaction`(`wallet_id`, `debit_amount`, `description`) VALUES ('3', '100', 'Debited For Service')
```

Comment: Have you tried to insert into database without these foreaches ?

Comment: What is in `$_REQUEST["enable"]` when the form is submitted? Also, it looks like you have a SQL injection vulnerability here - you will either need to escape your data, or better still, switch to a modern library that supports paramaterisation.

Comment: you want to add 4 values in to 3 fields ? or .. ?

Comment: If u want `data` value in to `debit_amount` then remove this `$data1` and if u want `data1` value in to `debit_amount` then remove `$data` from `$insert`

Comment: Also, ensure this is in a POST form and change `$_REQUEST` to `$_POST` - you should not run this in a GET method.

Answer (score 1):

Just use one loop, not nested loops, and access the corresponding elements of both arrays together.

```
foreach ($text as $i => $data) {
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    $data1 = mysql_real_escape_string($check[$i]);
    $insert="INSERT INTO `wallet_transaction`(`wallet_id`, `debit_amount`, `description`) VALUES ('$esc_id', '$data1', '$data', '$description')";
    mysql_query($insert);
}
```

There's another problem: you only have 3 columns listed to be inserted, but you have 4 values. I'm guessing that was just a copying error.

Answer (score 0):

it's probably because of you are firing your query in inner loop,

please go with this,

```
$text = $_REQUEST["enable"];
$description = 'Debited For Service';
foreach($text as $data)
{
    foreach($check as $data1)
    {
        $inData = $data;    
    }   
    $insert="INSERT INTO `wallet_transaction`(`wallet_id`, `debit_amount`, `description`) VALUES ('$esc_id', '$data1', '$inData', '$description')";
    mysql_query($insert);
}
```

guess this will work

Answer (score 0):

replace with below code, for quick solution

```
$quick_fix=1;
foreach($text as $data)
{
    if($quick_fix==1){
        foreach($check as $data1)
        {
            $insert="INSERT INTO `wallet_transaction`(`wallet_id`, `debit_amount`, `description`) VALUES ('$esc_id', '$data1', '$data', '$description')";
            mysql_query($insert);           
        }
        $quick_fix++;
    }
}
```